# tengo un problema con mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, php5

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Users\Tommy\Desktop\test\SERVER\htdocs\test\a1\Database\db_connection.php on line 2897

```
function __construct(){
           $hostname = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "t4_new";

            // Create connection
            $con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($con->connect_error) {
               die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
            }




function getOwnArtefactInfoByType($vref, $type) {
                global $con;
                $q = "SELECT * FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "artefacts WHERE vref = $vref AND type = $type order by size";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$q); //error aqui
                return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            }
```

Comment: Te falta depurar la consulta para ver que error exactamente se esta generando, toma nota de los ejemplos de aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples edita y muestranos que error estás obteniendo

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizar de esta forma si te funciona

```
$q = $con->query "SELECT * FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "artefacts WHERE vref = $vref AND type = $type order by size";
```

o si no de este modo

```
$result = mysqli_query->query($con,$q);
```

Comment: A tu query me parece le hacen falta los parentesis